# Desktop wallpaper only allowing solid colors in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop, desktop-customization

My Windows 7 32-bit Professional only allows solid colors on the desktop wallpaper. Any image selected won't be applied.

I've already tried the process described in the other SuperUser question (uncheck Remove Background Images on Ease of Access Center).

I've tried using REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v WallPaper /t REG_SZ /d "path_of_image.jpg" /f and it didn't work.

Also, I've read that Remote Access software can cause issues with the desktop wallpaper, but I haven't checked if that's the problem.

Another strange thing I noticed is that whenever I try to change the image, an "a.jpg" appears as selected. I've found that file at C:\ and it contains the Harmony default wallpaper. Is it possible that a script or software is setting the wallpaper to that file? Is it safe to delete it?

Comment: This link looked promising-- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5b9e513a-d504-451d-a121-b4f94893d96d/windows-7-enterprise-cant-change-background-image-only-set-as-solid-color?forum=w7itproui

Comment: Is your computer a member of a domain? There may be a Group Policy overriding your settings or preventing them from taking effect.

Comment: @Iszi - Would you like to add that as an answer? The OP confirmed that this fixed the issue.

Comment: Please don't add "[solved]" to the title. Instead, accept the answer to remove this question from the Unanswered list.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi - Actually, a single upvote on an answer is enough to remove it from the unanswered list. Acceptance just means that the answer 'worked for the OP'.

Comment: @Robotnik We'd rather have the author accept the answer than do what he's done now.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi I agree, but that wasn't my point :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your computer is a member of a domain, or has a Group Policy applied locally, you may not be able to change the wallpaper via the normal dialog or manual Registry edits. If you are not the person primarily responsible for maintaining the system and administering policy on it (in which case you would presumably be aware of this configuration and how to alter it), you should not try to change this. Remember, computers you use at work belong to the company - not you.